# Beginner question, do variables lose their values if inside multiple "while"s?

Tags: c, variables, while-loop

So I'm coding in C and compiling with gcc, I was attempting to create a simple code to display the Fibonacci sequence, you can input the amount of digits of the sequence you'd like to be displayed. Instead of the expected 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 etc. I get 0 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 etc. And I can't figure out why, if I remove the second "while" from the code, it works as intended, but I don't understand why. Do variables lose their values if they're inside multiple "while"s? Please help me figure this out. Again I'm a beginner so try to keep it simple.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num, num1 = 0, num2 = 1, cont = 0;
    printf("Insert the amount of digits of the Fibonacci sequence you'd like to display: \n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    if(num == 1){
        printf("%d ", num1);
    }    
    if(num >= 2){
        printf("%d ", num1);
        printf("%d ", num2);
    }
    while(cont < num - 2){
        num1 = num1 + num2;
        printf("%d ", num1);
        cont++;
        while(cont < num - 2){
            num2 = num1 + num2;
            printf("%d ", num2);
            cont++;
        }    
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your logic is flawed.  As soon as you break out of the inner loop, you will also break out of the outer loop.  num1 only gets incremented once.

Comment: Ahh I see now, simple logical blunder, thanks for helping me see it.

Comment: You might want to learn [to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your main question is no. Variables work like this: We declare a variable somewhere in our code. This variable has a name, a value (we either initialize it or it has a random value) and an address in memory. Your program has access to this variable within the block which this variable has been declared. In this particular example, because you declared the variable `cont` in the main function, that means wherever you change the value of this variable in the main function that change takes place.

The problem in your code is that the variable `num1` doesn't change accordingly and, in the whole program, has the value 1. That is the reason why the values printed change by 1. A piece of code that would solve this problem is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num, num1 = 0, num2 = 1, cont = 0,temp;
    printf("Insert the amount of digits of the Fibonacci sequence you'd like to display: \n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    if(num == 1){
        printf("%d ", num1);
    }    
    if(num >= 2){
        printf("%d ", num1);
        printf("%d ", num2);
    }
    while(cont < num - 2){
        temp = num2;
        num2 = num1 + num2;
        num1 = temp;
        printf("%d ", num2);
        cont++;   
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

This code just stores the value of `num2` in a variable `temp`, so we don't lose the value of `num2` because we want to modify it and the new value of variable `num1` must be the old value of variable `num2`.